# HTML5 video tag optimisation

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, html5-video

I have Angular app , which is build and serve with node/Express server .

I use a video that user can watch

```
<video width="100%" height="344" controls controlsList="nodownload" preload="metadata" autoplay>
   <source src="/assets/video/digital.mp4" type="video/mp4">            
</video>
```

It works fine . but on slow internet it play very slowly. I want to know what can be done here so user wont get frustrated even on slow internet .

Comment: Lower the quality of the video?

Comment: wow...is the video digital.mp4 fixed...is it the only video on the page ?

Comment: @Rajaji yes it is single video o

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes , but anything else .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **preload="metadata"** try **preload:"auto"**

> auto: indicates that the whole video file could be downloaded, even if
>   the user is not expected to use it.

But again as suggested the preload attribute is not always reliable..

There are 4 solutions mentioned [in this blog](http://dinbror.dk/blog/how-to-preload-entire-html5-video-before-play-solved/) & the most reliable being

> Solution #4, ajax and bloburl (works)

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'video.mp4', true);
req.responseType = 'blob';

req.onload = function() {
   // Onload is triggered even on 404
   // so we need to check the status code
   if (this.status === 200) {
      var videoBlob = this.response;
      var vid = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob); // IE10+
      // Video is now downloaded
      // and we can set it as source on the video element
      video.src = vid;
   }
}
req.onerror = function() {
   // Error
}

req.send();
```

Comment: video is around 90mb so I dont think , load once is good idea here it takes so much time

Comment: good thing about it is async... you can start the ajax call at body load or may be beginning of application start ..and also enable **cache** that way video will be downloaded only and only once on the server

Comment: Playing a video from a blob is extremely slow, I have no explanation why